# simple JSP CRUD

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

есть Сервлет такой, суть его работы : удалить, добавить, редактировать пользователей на JSP странице. Его необходимо переделать, чтобы в методах Гет и Пост был один метод,который вызывает нужный метод edit,delete и далее....как создать такой метод ? и как он должен выглядеть ? при этом методы Гет и Пост должны вызывать только этот метод.

```
public class UserController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/user.jsp";
private static String LIST_USER = "/listUser.jsp";
private UserDao dao;

public UserController() {
    super();
    dao = new UserDao();
}

private void delete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
     dao.deleteUser(userId);
     request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
}

private void edit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
     User user = dao.getUserById(userId);
     request.setAttribute("user", user);
}

private void listUsers(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forward="";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
        delete(request, response);
        forward = LIST_USER;
    /*    один метод, который различает внутри себя такой запрос и вызывает соответствующий метод common, edit..*/

    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
        edit(request, response);

    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")){
        forward = LIST_USER;
        listUsers(request, response);

    } else {
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
    user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
    try {
        Date dob = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("dob"));
        user.setDob(dob);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
    String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
    if(userid == null || userid.isEmpty())
    {
        dao.addUser(user);
    }
    else
    {
        user.setUserid(Integer.parseInt(userid));
        dao.updateUser(user);
    }
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_USER);
    listUsers(request, response);
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

}

Comment: ну так переделайте. Вопрос больше похож на заказ работы, чем на сам вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал,вот решение. буду рад если кому то поможет.

```
public class UserController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/user.jsp";
private static String LIST_USER = "/listUser.jsp";
private UserDao dao;

public UserController() {
    super();
    dao = new UserDao();
}

private void delete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
     dao.deleteUser(userId);
     request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
}

private void edit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
     User user = dao.getUserById(userId);
     request.setAttribute("user", user);
}

private void listUsers(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
}


private void common (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String forward="";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
        delete(request, response);
        forward = LIST_USER;
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
        edit(request, response);
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")){
        forward = LIST_USER;
       listUsers(request, response);
    } else {
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    try {
        view.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
    user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
    try {
        Date dob = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("dob"));
        user.setDob(dob);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
    String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
    if(userid == null || userid.isEmpty())
    {
        dao.addUser(user);
    }
    else
    {
        user.setUserid(Integer.parseInt(userid));
        dao.updateUser(user);
    }

    RequestDispatcher views = request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_USER);
    listUsers(request, response);
    try {
        views.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    common(request, response);

}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    common(request, response);

}
```

}